# Search for file or folder containing a keyword in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to find a file or folder containing a keyword. How can I do this from the command line? I am starting in a directory that I know contains this keyword somewhere, but am not sure where. It could be several directories down or could be just a couple.

I don't want to find the keyword inside a file, I want to find a directory or filename that includes the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd to directory and give command:

```
find | grep -i 'keyword'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep,

```
$> grep -r "keyword" /path/to/find/the/fil
```

If you want to find it from current location,

```
$> grep -r "keyword" .
```

man grep for detail usage.

Comment: grep looks inside files. I don't want to look inside files. I want the keyword to be part of the filename.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that. I think @rnso 's answer is what you want?